# How to get the response from Confirm box in the code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to asp.net/C# .I am trying to create a web application.

Below is my requirement.

I am trying to save a record on button click. Before saving the record,I will be checking if that record exist in the database or not(in the code behind).If it exist,then I need to show an alert to the user as "Record already exist.Do you want to proceed?"When the user press 'Yes',I need to continue my save for the record in the code ,else I just need to exit the save process.

```
//......code for checking the existence of the record    
if (check == true)
{            
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "script", " confirm('Record already exist.Do you want to proceed?');", true);
}
//
```

The above code shows me confirm box with 'OK' and 'Cancel' buttons.
My questions are

1. how can I make it 'Yes' or 'No' in the confirm dialog?
2. After the user press 'Yes'/'No',how can I catch the response(yes/no),and proceed with  rest of my program?

I have searched for this a lot.But couldn't get a proper answer.Please help me on this.

Comment: Are you already using Ajax Control Toolkit at this project?

Comment: The confirm box is only going to give javascript a value. Have you tried using javascript to assign this value to something that is posted back to the server?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in many ways:

One is place a button on the page, make its display:none and when confirm is true, trigger its click with js.

Like in aspx

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSaveData" 
     onClick="btnSaveData_Click" style="display:none;" />
```

in client side make a js function for calling confirmation dialog box, like

```
function ConfirmSave()
{
   if(confirm('Record already exist.Do you want to proceed?')
   {
       jQuery("[ID$=btnSaveData]").click();
   }

}
```

in Code Behind

Your code check in some event handler

```
if (check == true)
{            
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "script", 
      "ConfirmSave();", true);
}
```

bthSaveData click handler for saving data.

```
protected void btnSaveData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // Code for your saving.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for being complete in your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use confirm box in JS like this

```
var ans = confirm ('Record already exist.Do you want to proceed?');
if(ans==true)
{
}
else
{
}
```

Secondly, to get the response in code behind, you can store the Yes/No value into a hidden field e.g.

```
document.getElementById('<%= hiddenField.ClientID %>').value = ans;
```

Comment: You did not explain to this new user how to retrieve the value in the code behind, Yograj answer was better constructed and complete.

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at the this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8173/A-Simple-ASP-NET-Server-Control-Message-Box-Confir.

And more over you can create your own custom confirmation box.

Comment: Thanks all  for the answers.I have used radconfirm and two button click even for the same.Please see the link http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/window/need-to-show-confirm-window-through-code-behind.aspx for those who also have the same scenario.

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround can be to store the TRUE / FALSE flag in control that has the attribute runat="server", depending on the choice made by user (Yes / No). And then at the backend, you can check for the value of this control.

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX toolkit with modalpopupextender.

```
   <cc1:modalpopupextender id="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server"  cancelcontrolid="ButtonNo" okcontrolid="ButtonYes" popupcontrolid="PNL" targetcontrolid="UrSaveButton">
   </cc1:modalpopupextender>  
   <asp:Panel ID="PNL" runat="server" Style="display: none; width: 200px; background-color: #000099; border-width: 2px; border-color: Black; border-style: solid; padding: 20px;">
     <span style="color: White; font-weight: bold">Record already exist.Do you want to proceed?</span>
       <br />
        <br />
            <div style="text-align: right;">
                <asp:Button CssClass="tbl_blue" ID="ButtonYes" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" EnableTheming="false" Text="YES" />
                <asp:Button CssClass="tbl_blue" ID="ButtonNo" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" EnableTheming="false" Text="NO" />
             </div>
  </asp:Panel>
```

You can Customize it as you want.