# Javascript confirm box in C# code behind

Tags: c#, javascript

I am trying to show a javascript confirm box in the middle of some server side code and after getting user confirmation continue processing but confirm box does not show up. I even wrote some sample code but no success.

after some server processing I need to ask user a question and after user confirmation continue some other server code.  it seems to be very simple. even alert box  work. How can I solve it?

please note that I can not call javascript confirmbox straight from buttonclick I need to do some serverside code and if that was ok then I want to show a confirmbox for continuation.

here is the code

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_deletefromDB" runat="server" OnClick="btn_deletefromDB_Click"  Text="Delete from Datatbase);" />


protected void btn_deletefromDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

         //Delete service from Database 
        // some server side processing code
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "confirm", "return confirm('Do you want to delete it from runtime too? Click OK to proceed.');", true);
        Label1.Text = "delete from runtime confirmed";
        // continue and delete from runtime
        //bla bla bla

}
```

Comment: I used RegisterClientScriptBlock instead of RegisterStartupScript and it shows the confirm box at least but cancel does not work. Here some one had some suggestions I have not tested it yet though                 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643515/how-to-get-the-response-from-confirm-box-in-the-code-behind

Answer (score 3):

Instead of triggering this in the code-behind, you should add it to the `Button1 OnClientClick` event like so:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to delete it? Click OK to proceed.');" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Comment: I need to show confirm box after some processing not straight away by button click

Comment: You'll still want to do it all on the client-side.  Create a Javascript function on your page to perform the tasks you need to complete before allowing the delete.  Then call your Javascript function in the OnClientClick event: `OnClientClick="JavascriptFunctionName();"`  If you can't do it all client-side, you may need to rethink the button a little and your intention when it.

Comment: yes unfortunately the functions I need to do before showing confirm box can not be done in client side or maybe I am a beginner and do not know how to code complex things like database functions in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Web applications do not work like this. You cannot ask for user input in the middle of page's server-side life-cycle. This question has to be asked client-side and user's response has to come to the server as part of the page's submitted data.

All `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` does is contributes to the final `html` content that will be sent to the client when the page completes request processing. Keep in mind that by the time this `html` content arrives to client computer the user may have closed the browser and gone home.

Comment: the problem is I can not get confirm on button click I need to do some processing first. Is there a work around to do it?

Comment: Yes. Instead of submitting the page, you can issue an `ajax` request (use `jquery`), do the first half of the processing on the server, return some indication of success to the browser, in the `success` handler of `ajax` call javascript `confirm` and if the user confirms, submit the page and complete server-side operation.

Comment: soryy I am a newby can you explain more or if you can show me sample code I appreciate it. but I just used RegisterClientScriptBlock instead of RegisterStartupScript and it works

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "script", " confirm('Do you want to delete itfrom runtime too? Click OK to proceed');", true);

Answer (score 1):

Use AJAX to submit query to server and make the server code so that it does it’s processing in two parts. I don’t have any working examples of this but this is how it would work in general. For posting data to server you can use native AJAX objects in JS or any other library as others suggested and for processing data on the server side you can use generic handlers (ashx) instead of standard web pages.

1. Send request to the server.
2. Catch the first part of the processing via JS on the client page.
3. Show JS window
4. Submit the other part to server

You’ll have to send results of the first part of processing back to the client because server will not be able to connect second request with the first one by default.